# Failed to start the kernel in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

After reinstall anaconda3 (Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64) in Windows10. I got the following 'failed to start the kernel' error with Jupiter notebook (version 6.0.3). Please help with your idea. Many thanks.
Please see error image as attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQbjc.png)

########################

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 308, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 215, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

###################################################

```
[I 11:28:26.834 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 11:28:26.834 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 11:28:27.127 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 11:28:27.127 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 11:28:27.129 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Administrator
[I 11:28:27.129 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 11:28:27.129 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8890/?token=a6a1dace41d990751285a7d79a0134c18fb7e27403b72b9f
[I 11:28:27.129 NotebookApp] or http://127.0.0.1:8890/?token=a6a1dace41d990751285a7d79a0134c18fb7e27403b72b9f
[I 11:28:27.130 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 11:28:27.165 NotebookApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-4328-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8890/?token=a6a1dace41d990751285a7d79a0134c18fb7e27403b72b9f
or http://127.0.0.1:8890/?token=a6a1dace41d990751285a7d79a0134c18fb7e27403b72b9f
[E 11:28:34.207 NotebookApp] Failed to run command:
['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Anaconda3\\envs\\OpenPose\\python.exe', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-91bf3e96-0093-48bb-aed3-27ac4fd137ea.json']
PATH='C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\condabin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.0\\libnvvp;.;C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\windows\\System32\\OpenSSH;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NGX;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\swigwin-4.0.2;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Tensorflow;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NGX;C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin;C:\\windows\\System\\cmd.exe;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\wget-1.20.3-win64;C:\\tf-pose-estimation;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NGX;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin;C:\\Users\\Administrator\\wget-1.20.3-win64;C:\\tf-pose-estimation;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.2\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.2\\libnvvp;.'
with kwargs:
{'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator', 'close_fds': False}

[E 11:28:34.207 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception POST /api/sessions (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8890', method='POST', uri='/api/sessions', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
result = await result
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
model = yield maybe_future(
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 308, in start_kernel
self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 215, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[W 11:28:34.212 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 11:28:34.212 NotebookApp] {
"Host": "localhost:8890",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Length": "88",
"Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"87\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"87\"",
"Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
"X-Xsrftoken": "2|c377403e|a6d8d419183582cc511c7dc84109799d|1611520120",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Origin": "http://localhost:8890",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Referer": "http://localhost:8890/notebooks/David.ipynb",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cookie": "_xsrf=2|c377403e|a6d8d419183582cc511c7dc84109799d|1611520120; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1611573692|23:username-localhost-8889|44:MzQ4ZDkzMjBiZTFlNDFkNjk1OTM4Y2I5YjM5ZTNiNjg=|6b3cf989ea68afed756dee88608ef04356080625076e8bf271c374ac0eafc5cd\"; username-localhost-8890=\"2|1:0|10:1611574108|23:username-localhost-8890|44:ZDRmZDJjMWVlYTYxNDBhMGI0YjJkYmIzYzFiNTU5MDk=|dd855fdb4b3e8eb95c7a10159ac248d68e26591d7e67121fdd5eb03e494e70c7\""
}
[E 11:28:34.212 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/sessions (::1) 34.91ms referer=http://localhost:8890/n

otebooks/David.ipynb
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative simple solution is:

1. Open your Anaconda Prompt.
2. Activate your env (this step is optional if you don't work with envs)
3. run: python -m ipykernel install --user
4. Start your jupyter notebook

Check https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4079 for more information

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. Steps are listed below:

First, stop those running or dead servers,  from anaconda prompt:

```
jupyter notebook list (list currently running servers)

jupyter notebook stop [port number] (e.g. jupyter notebook stop 8888)

jupyter --paths (Check where your runtime folder is located)

del -r [path to runtime folder]/*
```

Second, remove jupyter notebook and reinstall it, from anaconda navigator:

- jupyter notebook->remove application
- then manually delete the jupyter folder: AppData\Roaming\jupyter (AppData might be a hidden folder)
- re-install jupyter notebook

Moreover, I uninstalled python 3.7 to avoid any conflicts, since python 3.8 is installed with anaconda3, however not sure if that also helps.